# unexpected EOF while parsing in plot

Tags: python, math, plot, sage

I am tring to plot this:

```py
plot((1-exp(3*t))/(4-exp(3*t))
```

but have an error:

```
 <ipython-input-28-258203e92a41> in <module>
----> 1 plot(Integer(1)-exp(Integer(3)*t))/(Integer(4)-exp(Integer(3)*t))

  File "<ipython-input-29-0cc6c8b31567>", line 1
    plot((Integer(1)-exp(Integer(3)*t))/(Integer(4)-exp(Integer(3)*t))
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: You forgot a parenthesis at the end!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
plot((1-exp(3*t))/(4-exp(3*t)))
```